# Mysql Can't connect to local server through socket

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash, mysql

This is the error i receive:

I can not connect as any user and it continually says

```
"Can't connect to local server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (2)"
```

and

```
"Can't connect to local server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (111)"
```

Output of lsof -i -P | grep :3306

```
xxx$ lsof -i -P | grep :3306
xxx$ mysqld 20080 mysql 11u IPv4 56434 0t0 TCP localhost.localdomain:3306 (LISTEN)
```

Narrowed it down a little bit. Whenever I select one of my databases and type

```
show tables;
```

I receive

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket                     '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR:
Can't connect to the server
```

However I can select the other databases just fine. I can't remove the database.

**Update**

Had to manually remove the problem database and can now connect successfully to mysql.

Comment: did you check if that socket file actually exists? did you check if mysql's running?

Comment: When i try to start mysql with sudo sudo service mysqld start it says mysqld is unrecognised service. However was working earlier today.

Comment: Your pastebin link is reporting: "This paste has been removed!". Please post your error here.

Comment: What does the output of the following command say.  lsof -i -P | grep :3306

Comment: Sorry, it is very long. This link will work now: http://pastebin.com/nw1Hf0DT

Comment: mysqld  20080    mysql   11u  IPv4  56434      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:3306 (LISTEN)


Is what it says in regards to apesa.

Comment: That shows you already have a MySQL daemon running on 3306. Your error message says the same. Looks like you're trying to restart MySQL when it is already running

Comment: I have used /etc/init.d/mysql stop to stop the mysql server before i start it.

Comment: What does the command mysql give you

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

When i log in I can select a database but if I type for example `show tables;` it tells me it can not connect to local server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I also receive this error log:
http://pastebin.com/PQu46eQb

Comment: Did you set a root password when you installed mysql

Comment: Yes, i logged in with the root user and password after receiving the error that access was denied.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to MySQL from the same box? i.e, localhost?

If you are on a linux box, make sure you can telnet localhost on port 3306

`telnet localhost 3306`

If your telnet connects then it must be a permissions issue:

Check the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf and make change the bind-adress so it looks like:

bind-addess = 0.0.0.0

If none of the above works, then please post your mysql log

Comment: Hi, I tried 

telnet localhost 3306 

it connects successfully.

Mysql now fails to start, this is the error log:

http://pastebin.com/iER1BZgM

Comment: If you're connecting on Localhost your bind-address should be 127.0.0.1

Comment: I've changed that, this is the error log that i receive now: http://pastebin.com/PQu46eQb

Comment: Are you connecting to MySQL as root ? if not, remember to grant privileges to the user

Comment: Was an issue with a corrupt table/database which would stop me from connecting mysql. Thanks for your help though!